# How to use functools.wraps and set one argument

Tags: python

I tried to research this question but couldn't find an answer -- sorry if I missed it. Basically, I have the following question. I have a function:

```py
def f(a, b, c, d, e):
    ...
```

I also have a second function which calls `f` but infers some arguments from `a`:

```py
def g(a, **kwargs):
    b = deduce(a)
    return f(a, b, **kwargs)
```

Now it would be great to copy over the `kwargs` from `f` with `functools.wraps`. But I can't use it directly, because the signature of `f` does not match that of `g`: the argument `b` is fixed in `g`. I would love a way to make it clear that `g` is the function `f`, but with `b` deduced.

I hope the problem is clear; I'm curious to hear your thoughts!

Comment: Is the goal here for providing documentation or validation in tools like mypy?

Comment: hmm, wondering why you can't define it without b, like `g(a, c, d, e)`? Is that because you would need the signature to match that of `f` in this case.

Comment: @flakes not immediately! Mostly I am hoping to avoid having to manually duplicate all the `kwargs` from `f` in `g`, which would mean I'd have to update them in multiple places if I change one of them (especially as there will be functions `h` etc. who also call `f` but deduce different `b`s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think in this case, just having a clear docstring will be all you need. `functools.wraps` is more useful for decorators that are going to replace the original definition entirely. For a separate function (where both `g` and `f` are still referenced independently) you shouldn't be using that.

You also need to handle the case where the user didn't provide keyword args. For example, this code will fail:

```
>>> f(1,2,3,4,5)
>>> g(1,3,4,5)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: g() takes 1 positional argument but 4 were given
```

For `g` to work you would need to do:

```
def g(a, *args, **kwargs):
    b = deduce(a)
    return f(a, b, *args, **kwargs)
```

Additionally, if you're worried about the signature of `f` changing underneath `g`, then you should also guard against the order of the starting arguments changing.

To make `f` as nice as possible to work with when it comes to changing the signature, it might be worth prohibiting the use of positional arguments altogether. (and also adding that nice docstring):

```
def f(*, a, b, c, d, e):
    ...


def g(*, a, **kwargs):
    """
    Acts in the same way as function `f`, however, argument `b` must
    be omitted as it will be deduced from `a`.
    """

    return f(**kwargs, a=a, b=deduce(a))
```

This also keeps the nice side-effect of prohibiting you from calling `g` with `b` explicitly defined:

```
>>> g(a=1, b=2, c=3, d=4, e=0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<input>", line 14, in g
TypeError: __main__.f() got multiple values for keyword argument 'b'
```

---

Considerations for mypy.

If this is a library that will get used by many people, it's nicer if the values are explicitly listed out in the signature. This will allow static analysis tools to catch bugs before runtime.

This is error prone when you have a lot of arguments, but using a `pyi` stub file, you only have to do this once (and not for the actual code that gets executed). The boiler-plate in your actual code stays minimal, and the intended definition becomes clear for users.

`g.py`

```
def g(*, a, **kwargs):
    """
    Acts in the same way as function `f`, however, argument `b` must
    be omitted as it will be deduced from `a`.
    """

    return f(**kwargs, a=a, b=deduce(a))
```

`g.pyi`

```
def g(*, a, c, d, e): ...
```